# Which capabilities do Java applets executed in a browser have?

Tags: macos, plugins, java-applet, sandbox

I found a [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) on the Oracle website,
, that lists the capabilities of unsigned applets, unsigned applets with JNLP and signed applets.
When i encounter an unsigned applet on a webpage (I am using Firefox), a popup says:

> "this application will run with unrestricted access"

asking whether to execute it or not.

I don't understand if the applet is already being executed in the sandbox without explicit consent and now it is asking for more privileges, or if it is waiting for approval to be executed.

What happens if the signed applet certificate is expired, unvalid, or simply refused by the user?
What level of privilege is assigned to the applet showing a request like this?

---

The question refers to the Java 7 implementation provided by Oracle in its binaries, as a plugin for 64 bit web browsers on OS X, that can be found at http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

**Note**: In the second case the warning appear misleading to me, since (exploits aside) it will not be run with unfettered access to the system (not root neither current user's privileges), or at least this is what the guide said. In the first case this would mean that the system is unnecessarily exposing the Java functionality to every website I visit, that leaves plenty of room for exploits to break the sandbox.

Comment: Hi Valentine! Please *register* your account here, so you can stay logged in, comment on your posts and edit them. I've merged your (unregistered) accounts for now, but that probably won't hold long.